# Unable to retrieve values from database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-config, dataset, connection-string

I am doing first asp.net app, now need to connect it to SQL (Using MS SQL 2008), but I am unable to get any value from the tables.

My web.config is:

```
<add name="MainConnectString" connectionString="Data Source=LUCKYY-PC;initial catalog=testDbName;uid=sa;Password=123456;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

In backend Code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string query = "select * from [testTableName]";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                conn.Open();
                string numRows = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                dataGrid.DataSource = ds;
                conn.Close();                
            }
```

dataGrid is the datagrid name i have defined on ascx page of this code.

but **'ds' appears with 0** count, and so the datagrid is blank, I don't know if I am missing anything on code or in web.config ...any help will be appreciated

Comment: you forget to call dataGrid.DataBind() method

Comment: Ah Ok Mohsen but ds is already blank, wat about that ?

Comment: what is the value of numRows, is it 0 or not ?

Comment: ExecuteScalar() does not return a count like you seem to be expecting.  It returns the first column of the first row...all other columns/rows are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dataGrid.DataBind()  - filled the datagrid, thanks Mohsen

Comment: I sent my comment as answer with more details .

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string. I think you had make mistake in writing data source, I think you are using SQL server 2005/2008/2008 R2, and so data source must be to set as **.(DOT)** or **localhost**. Try this one may be it can help you.....

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems in your code:

1. As @ethorn10 commented, `ExecuteScalar()` as you are using it won't give you what you expecting. Change your query to:

   ```
   string query = "select count(*) from [testTableName]";
   ```
2. You have forgotten to call the *datagrid* `DataBind()` method to show the records selected from `datasource`.

   ```
   dataGrid.DataSource = ds;
   dataGrid.DataBind();
   ```

If you are new to asp.net, I strongly recommend you to learn and use [Entity framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) instead of using the old ADO.net code like yours.